# laravel 5.2 belongsTo relation not work

Tags: php, laravel-5, belongs-to

I'd like to get some additional user information from the divisions table.

But not work why?

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81: Method division does
>   not exist.

class AdminsController extends Controller

```
public function getUserIndex()
{
  $users = User::all()->division();
  dd($users);
}
```

class User extends Authenticatable

```
public function division()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Division', 'division_id');
}
```

class Division extends Model

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Users table

```
$table->foreign('division_id')->references('id')->on('divisions')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Divisions table

```
$table->increments('id');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `division()` relationship is defined for each individual table row. By calling it on `all()`, you're attempting to get the relationship for all rows.

You should be able to use something like:

```
public function getUserIndex()
{
    $users = User::all();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        dd($user->division());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. It's work.`dd($user->division()->first()->name);`